# Does .BeginInvoke always need .EndInvoke for Threadpool threads?

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

So C#/.NET question. Do I always need to call .EndInvoke when invoking asynchronously with .BeginInvoke some method? I have read somewhere it is mandatory, but the problem is .EndInvoke will block execution? Is there some kind of universal solution?

Comment: Consider using `Task`. Much better API.

Comment: So don't call EndInvoke *until you know it will not block* if you don't want it to block.  (And yes, usr is right: use `Task<T>` instead. C# 5 has an `await` operator now.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do have to call `EndInvoke()`.

> but the problem is .EndInvoke will block execution?

Not when you call it from the callback method, which is the proper patttern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is mandatory for 2 reasons:
1)  to avoid possible resoure leak
2)  to catch any Exception that might have been thrown

Below is example code:

```
public delegate void DelegateHelper2(..parameters...);
private void ff(..parameters...);{}
DelegateHelper2 myDelegate =  new DelegateHelper2(ff);
// invoke asynchronyously 
IAsyncResult result = myDelegate.BeginInvoke(..parameters..., CallBackEmpty, null);

....
private void CallBackEmpty(IAsyncResult iasync)
{
    if (iasync != null)
    {
        string typeName = "";
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult aresult =
                (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)iasync;
            object action1 = aresult.AsyncDelegate;
            Type actionType = action1.GetType();
            typeName = actionType.ToString();

            if (action1 != null)
            {
                //action1.EndInvoke(iasync);
                actionType.InvokeMember("EndInvoke",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                    action1, new object[] { iasync });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = "CallBackEmpty; for type: " + typeName +
                " ;Exception: " + ex.ToString();
            Setup_TraceExceptions(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is demo of Universal Calback method that calls EndInvoke. Universal, becouse it will work for all delgates, otherwise you need CallBackMethod version for each delegate type. That is why a little trick with reflection is done.

Comment: Check below..I have explained tricks applied in this example.. and given plain sample.. if this one is too complicated

Comment: Wow... what an impossibly detailed answer to come up with in *two minutes*

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems people are confused with tricks applied above. I will explain. Here is your regular solution, when using .BeginInvoke to spawn a thread and forget it:

```
private void ff(..parameters...);{}
DelegateHelper2 myDelegate =  new DelegateHelper2(ff);
// invoke asynchronyously 
IAsyncResult result = myDelegate.BeginInvoke(..parameters..., CallBack2, myDelegate);

private void CallBack2(IAsyncResult iasync)
{
    if (iasync != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DelegateHelper2 action1 = (DelegateHelper2)iasync.AsyncState;
            action1.EndInvoke(iasync);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Trace exeption somehow 
        }
    }
}
```

There are problems:
1)  You need to pass separtely callBack delgate and delgate itself
2)  If you are using this pattern offten, (spawning threads in this way), you need for each .BeginInvoke to write a new CallBack method, becous inside it you refer to specific delegate type(DelegateHelper2). ( I in my code have maybe 8 such calls, that would result in 8 different CallBack methods etc. )

Above example does trick and solves those problems, in a this way:
1)  You pass only CallBack delegate, action1 is obtained from IAsyncResult
2)  Only one CallBack method is needed, since it does not depend on delegate type (that is solved by reflection)

Comment: Totally makes sense to me. Starting with .NET 4.0 Tasks can simplify this a lot, though.

Comment: I like both answers but, i think the first one is a little too convoluted for me..